# How can I load certain JavaScripts only on blog pages?

Tags: javascript, footer

Here's the situation I'm having. I am developing a site and on the single post pages of the site I am using various social sharing buttons (i.e. Google+, Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, etc). I am following the official developer documentation for each of these buttons and most of them require inserting JavaScript before the closing  tag.

This is all fine and dandy and I've got it working perfectly. However, my only issue is that since these social icons are ONLY on the single post blog pages I don't want that JavaScript being loaded on other pages as it will only add unnecessary resources to be loaded and I'd like to keep my page speed as fast as possible.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to go about doing this. I thought at first about writing some conditional PHP code that detected if you were on a single post page and if so it loaded the scripts in the footer. However, I realized that I don't think there's a realistic way to do that since each single post URL doesn't have a consistent part of the URL in it (i.e. /blog/).

I could add the JavaScripts to the single.php template for single post pages but that wouldn't work either since it's calling the footer in those pages via  and I would like these scripts to be loaded in the footer, not the template itself.

Anyways, any input would be appreciated. I'm sure there is a way to do it, I'm just racking my brain and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

1. Properly **enqueue** the scripts, via callback hooked into the appropriate hook
2. Use contextual **conditional tags** to determine when to enqueue

For example, you'd do something like:

```
function wpse135482_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Only enqueue this script on single post pages
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( $args );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse135482_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Further reading:

- [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)
- [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)/[`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)